# Why series expansion in evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\arccos(1-x^2)}{x}=\sqrt2$ is not working here?

Tags: limits

Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\arccos(1-x^2)}{x}=\sqrt2$

---

I can evaluate this limit using L Hospital rule but i wonder why Series expansion method is failing here and L Hospital rule is working here. 
$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\arccos(1-x^2)}{x}$
As $\arccos(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-x-\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{3x^5}{40}-....$
$\arccos(1-x^2)=\frac{\pi}{2}-(1-x^2)-\frac{(1-x^2)^3}{6}-\frac{3(1-x^2)^5}{40}-....$
$\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-(1-x^2)-\frac{(1-x^2)^3}{6}-\frac{3(1-x^2)^5}{40}-....}{x}$
And it is not simplifying.I cannot take $x$ common from the numerator to cancel out from the denominator.
Have i made some mistake or series expansion will not work here.
Are there some cases where series expansion fails and only L Hospital works.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: You are using a series expansion **around $0$.** When plugging in $1-x^2$, the (infinite) series is still exact,but you cannot truncate it and keep only the first few terms: this would be only valid if $1-x^2\simeq 0$, which is not the case when $x\to0$.

Comment: Should i expand it around $1$,as $1-x^2\to 1$ as $x\to 0$.Will then it work and will that be OK.@ClementC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x\to0,1-x^2>0$

$\arccos(1-x^2)=\arcsin\sqrt{1-(1-x^2)^2}=\arcsin\sqrt{2x^2-x^4}$

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac{\arcsin\sqrt{2x^2-x^4}}x=\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac{\arcsin\sqrt{2x^2-x^4}}{\sqrt{2x^2-x^4}}\cdot\lim_{x\to0^+}\dfrac{x\sqrt{2-x^2}}x$$

Set $\arcsin\sqrt{2x^2-x^4}=y$ in the first

Can you take it home from here?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $\arccos(1-x^2)=2y\implies1-x^2=\cos2y\iff x^2=1-\cos2y=2\sin^2y$

As $0\le2y\le\pi, \sin y\ge0$

and $x>0, x=\sqrt2\sin y$

Can you take it home from here?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we can expand the arccosine directly.

> **Relatedly**:
>
> Note that in [This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312182/convergence-int-01-log-arctanx-dfrac-frac-pi2-arcsinxe1-x/1312270#1312270), I showed a way to expand $\arcsin(x)$ around $x=1$.

Let $f(x)=\arccos(1-x^2)$.  Then, for $x\ne 0$

$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-(1-x^2)^2}}\\\\
&=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{2x^2-x^4}}\\\\
&=\frac{2x}{|x|}\left(2-x^2\right)^{-1/2}\\\\
&=2\text{sgn}(x)\left(2-x^2\right)^{-1/2}
\end{align}$$

Note that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{\pm}}f'(x)=\pm \sqrt{2}$.  We find, therefore, that

$$f(x)=\sqrt{2}|x|+O\left(|x|^3\right)$$

and the coveted limit is given by

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\,\frac{\arccos(x)}x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\,\,|x|+O\left(|x|^3\right)}x\right)=\sqrt 2$$

as was to be shown!